# stockPortfolio::getReturns does not seem to work

Tags: r, finance, portfolio

`stockPortfolio::getReturns` does not seem to work for me.

To make sure that there is no confusion with `timeSeries::returns` I typed

```
d <- stockPortfolio::getReturns(c("VWINX", "GOOG"))
# Fehler in unclass(e1) + unclass(e2) :
#  nicht-numerisches Argument für binären Operator
```

Which in English means

```
error in unclass(e1) + unclass(e2) :
  non-numeric Argument for binary Operator
```

Any ideas what's going on here?

Thanks,

Dietmar

This is what sessionInfo gives me

> sessionInfo()
>   R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
>   Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)
>   
>   locale:
>   [1] de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8/C/de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8
>   attached base packages:
>   [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
>   
>   other attached packages:
>   [1] stockPortfolio_1.2 plotrix_3.5-3
>   
>   loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
>   [1] tools_3.0.2

Comment: Your code works for me. Does the problem persist if you run it in a new session? What is the output of `sessionInfo()`?